# Build a wallet for Android and iOS for a self-made cryptocurrency

Tags: wallet, altcoin, altcoin-development, android, ios

I've built a cryptocurrency of my own using [this video guide](https://steemit.com/steem/@marsresident/make-your-own-cryptocurrency-video-tutorial). I did the first 4 steps out of 6, as the 5th level is about building a wallet for Windows platform.

I have started creating this cryptocurrency so it would be able to trade using it only on mobile devices running Android and iOS. Right now I would like to start to develop it for Android platform.

My question is how can I create a wallet for Android using Java that will support my self-made cryptocurrency? By wallet I mean to store the coins, send and receive them, and ability to open new wallets.

Answer (score 1):

You first should learn how to create an android app if you don't know how to do that already. There are lots of resources available for this and better places to ask questions than the bitcoin stackexchange.

Then once you are comfortable with that most android wallets are built using bitcoinj. I don't know of any nice step-by-step guide. Here is a sample github project for bitcoin that should give you a good starting point. https://github.com/thinkmobiles/BitcoinJ-Wallet-Sample-Android. I don't know anything about your coin but you will obviously need to make some fairly critical changes.